# How to setup multiple HABTM relationships between two tables in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to make two HABTM relationships between these two tables in CAKEPHP 2.6, but it gives me a database error when I try to create a record. I'm sure there must be some model settings or something, but I could not fix it. :(

Here's an img of DB structure:
[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/k4wkyh.jpg]

Model

```
class Solicitude extends AppModel {
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Citante' => array(
        'className' => 'Cliente',
        'joinTable' => 'citantes',
        'foreignKey' => 'solicitude_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'cliente_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
    ),
    'Citado' => array(
        'className' => 'Cliente',
        'joinTable' => 'citados',
        'foreignKey' => 'solicitude_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'cliente_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
    )
);
```

}

Controller ADD method

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Solicitude->create();
        if ($this->Solicitude->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The solicitude has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The solicitude could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $citantes = $this->Solicitude->Citante->find('list');
    $citados = $this->Solicitude->Citado->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('citantes', 'citados'));
}
```

Add view

```
echo $this->Form->create('Solicitude');
```

echo __('Add Solicitude');

```
    echo $this->Form->input('radicado');
    echo $this->Form->input('fecha');
    echo $this->Form->input('ccsede_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('ccusuario_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('consulta_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('peticiones');
    echo $this->Form->input('area_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('tipo_clase_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('Citante');
    echo $this->Form->input('Citado');
```

echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));

Error obtained adding

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Citante.cliente_id' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `Citante`.`cliente_id` FROM `conciliacion`.`clientes` AS `Citante` WHERE `Citante`.`solicitude_id` = '1'

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To help with getting answers to your question faster, it would be great if you could share the code that you're trying to use at the moment.

Comment: Please put the code in your question and format it. It is not readable in a comment.

Comment: it is ok formated now..

Comment: What line gives the error ? the `find('list')` ? These queries are done by the `Client` model, as `Citante` and `Citado` are aliases for `Client` and the find() is called on them. The problem is probably to look in the `Client` class. Most of the time, relations must be declared in both ways.

Comment: The error is adding a record on submit

Answer (score 0):

With CakePHP 2 you can define these relations like this in your `Solicitude` model:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(

        'Citantes' => array(
            'className' => 'Client',
            'joinTable' => 'citantes',
            'foreignKey' => 'solicitude_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'cliente_id'
        ),
        'Citados' => array(
            'className' => 'Client',
            'joinTable' => 'citados',
            'foreignKey' => 'solicitude_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'cliente_id'
        )
    );
```

The only thing you have to two is to set two different relation names, here `Citantes` and `Citados`. They are then the names that are used to fetch records.

And with CakePHP 3, this would be done like this in your `SolicitudesTable` table:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Citantes', [
            'className' => 'Client',
            'joinTable' => 'citantes',
            'foreignKey' => 'solicitude_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'cliente_id'
        ]);

$this->belongsToMany('Citados', [
            'className' => 'Client',
            'joinTable' => 'citados',
            'foreignKey' => 'solicitude_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'cliente_id'
        ]);
```

Comment: Hi...and thank u ..
I have this in my model

 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
  'Citante' => array(
   'className' => 'Cliente',
   'joinTable' => 'citantes',
   'foreignKey' => 'solicitude_id',
   'associationForeignKey' => 'cliente_id',
   'unique' => 'keepExisting',
  ),
  'Citado' => array(
   'className' => 'Cliente',
   'joinTable' => 'citados',
   'foreignKey' => 'solicitude_id',
   'associationForeignKey' => 'cliente_id',
   'unique' => 'keepExisting',
  )
 );

Comment: But when i m adding i m getting that error..
 Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Citante.cliente_id' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `Citante`.`cliente_id` FROM `conciliacion`.`clientes` AS `Citante` WHERE `Citante`.`solicitude_id` = '1'